# How to set a row for grid-view in android?

Tags: android, xml, gridview

Right now i am displaying the data from XML file in to grid view in android.This is the exact xml's file link

"http://54.251.60.177/StudentWebService/StudentDetail.asmx/GetTMSOrders"  which 
i am trying to show.I have done that concept successfully, but here the problem is,i am not getting the answer like the below image

i need to show like the below image, in android

[image]

but i am getting only like the below image.....

[image]

How to overcome this concept?can any one please make me clear?

thanks for your precious time!..

Here my sources for reference,please find

**GridviewSample.java**

```
public class GridviewSample extends Activity 
{

// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://54.251.60.177/StudentWebService/StudentDetail.asmx/GetTMSOrders";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_TABLE = "Table"; // parent node
static final String KEY_CUST = "Cust_Name";
static final String KEY_ORDER = "Order_No";
static final String KEY_FREIGHT = "Freight_Rate";
static final String KEY_STATION1 = "Station_Name";
static final String KEY_STATION2 = "Station_Name1";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GridView gv =  (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();

    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML

    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_TABLE);

    // looping through all item nodes <item>

    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) 
    {
        // creating new HashMap

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

        map.put(KEY_CUST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_CUST));
        map.put(KEY_ORDER, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ORDER));
        map.put(KEY_FREIGHT, parser.getValue(e, KEY_FREIGHT));
        map.put(KEY_STATION1, parser.getValue(e, KEY_STATION1));
        map.put(KEY_STATION2, parser.getValue(e, KEY_STATION2));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
    }

    // Adding menuItems to ListView

 SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,R.layout.grid_item,
 new String[] { KEY_CUST, KEY_ORDER, KEY_FREIGHT,KEY_STATION1,KEY_STATION2 }, new int[] 
 {
    R.id.cust, R.id.order, R.id.freight,R.id.statio1,R.id.station2 });


    gv.setAdapter(adapter);

    gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> Table, View v,int position, long id) 
    {


    String cust = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cust)).getText().toString();
    String order = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.order)).getText().toString();
    String freight = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.freight)).getText().toString();
    String station1 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.statio1)).getText().toString();
    String station2 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.station2)).getText().toString();

    // Starting new intent

    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Single_gridview_item.class);

      in.putExtra(KEY_CUST, cust);
      in.putExtra(KEY_ORDER, order);
      in.putExtra(KEY_FREIGHT, freight);
      in.putExtra(KEY_STATION1, station1);
      in.putExtra(KEY_STATION2, station2);
      startActivity(in);
      }
    }); 
}   }
```

**Single_gridview_item**

```
public class Single_gridview_item  extends Activity
{

// XML node keys

static final String KEY_TABLE = "Table"; // parent node
static final String KEY_CUST_NAME = "Cust_Name";
static final String KEY_ORDER = "Order_No";
static final String KEY_FREIGHT = "Freight_Rate";
static final String KEY_STATION1 = "Station_Name";
static final String KEY_STATION2="Station_Name1";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_grid_item);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get XML values from previous intent
    String cust = in.getStringExtra(KEY_CUST_NAME);
    String order = in.getStringExtra(KEY_ORDER);
    String freight = in.getStringExtra(KEY_FREIGHT);
    String station1 = in.getStringExtra(KEY_STATION1);
    String station2 = in.getStringExtra(KEY_STATION2);

    // Displaying all values on the screen

    TextView lblcust = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cust_label);
    TextView lblorder = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.order_label);
    TextView lblfreight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.freight_label);
    TextView lblstation1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.station1_label);
    TextView lblstation2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.station2_label);

    lblcust.setText(cust);
    lblorder.setText(order);
    lblfreight.setText(freight);
    lblstation1.setText(station1);
    lblstation2.setText(station2);
}}
```

**XMLParser.java**

```
public class XMLParser {

// constructor
public XMLParser() {

}

/**
 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
 * @param url string
 * */
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

/**
 * Getting XML DOM element
 * @param XML string
 * */
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}

/** Getting node value
  * @param elem element
  */
 public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node child;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return child.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 /**
  * Getting node value
  * @param Element node
  * @param key string
  * */
 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a grid view, it won't help you. It is designed to display a list of items as a grid. You may specify the number of columns, but displaying a table is more of a job for a TableLayout.

Comment: Okay....then how to achieve this concept....can you please send me at least one example....