# How to arrange the rows and columns in gridview in android?

Tags: android, xml, gridview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set a row for grid-view in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248891/how-to-set-a-row-for-grid-view-in-android)

Now i am displaying the data from XML file in to grid view in android.This is the exact xml's file link

"http://54.251.60.177/StudentWebService/StudentDetail.asmx/GetTMSOrders"

which i am trying to show.
I have done that concept successfully, but here the problem is,i am not getting the answer like the below image

i need to show like the below image, in android

[image]

but i am getting only like the below image.....
[image]

![enter image description here][3]

How to overcome this concept?can any one please make me clear?

thanks for your precious time!..

Comment: Try `ListView` or `ListAtivity`.

Comment: @AVD if i extend my class by ListView or ListActivity,i cannot able to run my project....What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below layout in your code has grid_layout.xml, it may help you a while.Better to use Listview for these kind of implementation.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        style="@style/gridViewStyle" />
```

under styles.xml place the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- GridView Style -->
    <style name="gridViewStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:columnWidth">60dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:horizontalSpacing">10dp</item>    
        <item name="android:numColumns">3</item>
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:stretchMode">columnWidth</item>
        <item name="android:verticalSpacing">10dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

place your relevant Listitems in your grid_items.xml has below

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget44"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="201px"
    android:layout_y="165px"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/icon_image"
        style="@style/wrapViewScale"/ >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/icon_text"
        style="@style/wrapViewScale"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/text_color_highlight" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In grid_items.xml is showing some error when i place the above code in to my project's grid_item.xml

Comment: Every code is perfect what you have given to me.....but except grid_item.xml

Comment: from grid_item.xml replace style into android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" remove color attributes

Comment: actually its showing the result in the form of grid fine....but i need to show the answer like the above image.....please clearly visit my question and make me clear

Comment: for this kind of implementation you need to go for ListView..place an header above layout first and plave your listview...

Comment: do you have example programs belongs to this concept...if so please send me at least one sample...actually i am self learner to android and java

Answer (score 0):

stick with gridview , and change the childview by inflating custom xml file

Comment: Can you send me one sample.......